# ZF2 Trouble using dependancy injection in Vendor library

Tags: php, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

So I have the following dilemma.  I want to have a common library that all my ZF2 applications will use.  This library will contain all the business logic for my website.  Each application will consume different parts of the library to properly display/perform whatever actions are necessary.  Now so far I've managed to create a library.  Lets call it Foo.  Foo has a Module.php which does the basic autoloading required to load the entire library.

Now here is where I start to have problems.  I want to take advantage of dependency injection, the service manager, etc from ZF2 inside Foo.  The problem is I only have the one Module.php that loads Foo.  This means as my library grows so will Module.php since as far as I can tell I can't have sub modules.  Is there any way around this issue?

Essentially I want every app to just include Foo and Foo to have several Module.php so that at least the dependency stuff can be handled on a module by module basis.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably swimming against the current to try and do sub-modules -- and you probably don't need to.

If you've written your module nicely, loading it won't be a very expensive operation.  Remember, the whole point of the service manager is that all those services are lazily created.  So if the calling code never asks for a particular service in a particular request, that service's classfile is never autoloaded, the object is never instantiated, etc.  So  you may be fine staying with a big, monolithic, module.

The one place that things might get a little tricky is if you're leaning heavily on the EventManager, and your module is attaching a bunch listeners.  But you can probably get around that by setting up some module configuration directives, and then just conditionally attach listeners.

Having said that, it probably makes sense to try to split your module up.  So you could have FooBar and FooBaz modules.

If you really, really, want sub-modules, you can dig into the ModuleManager and try to figure it out.  I went a little ways down that road once -- and then got distracted.  In my case, I was dealing with shipping physical items.  I wanted a "Fulfillment" module that could be configured to load a bunch of similar shipping modules (Fulfillment\Courier\USPSModule, Fulfillment\Courier\FedExModule, etc), so that my main Fulfillment module could iterate over all loaded submodules, without specific knowledge about any of them.  If I recall correctly, the best way to do it was to essentially mirror what ZF2 does, but inside my Fulfillment\Module class.  However, I can't think of many situations where you'd want to do that, unless you want a set of similar submodules that all implement the same interface, and want them to be consumed by a super-module that has no specific knowledge of them.  I also looked at this because was thinking about runtime enabling/disabling of those submodules by end-users (sort of like a plugin system).

If you're not doing that, I'd say stick to FooBarModule, FooBazModule, etc, so far as it makes sense.  And remember even if your module contains a ton of code, the ServiceManager will only autoload, parse, and instantiate classes that are needed to satisfy the dependencies of any given request.